# How can I align labels and textboxes in asp.net?

Tags: css, asp.net, vb.net

[image: This is the output]

I use spaces to align labels but it didnt work properly.
I also put all labels into panels to align it horizontally. 
 my code look like this

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel4" runat="server">


        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;


        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Last Name"></asp:Label>



        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;



        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="First Name"></asp:Label>



        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Middle Name"></asp:Label>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;



        <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" Text="Tuition"></asp:Label>



        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblTuition" runat="server" BorderWidth="1px" Width="75px"></asp:Label>



    </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: You can't. asp.net is a server-side language. You should use css for that.

Comment: So what are the syntax using css to align these labels?

Comment: I have no idea what your html looks like... you should start with that.

Comment: I edited my post, I add some codes

Comment: This is not HTML. You should add the **output** of this code.

Comment: @Dekel I added the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bro take a look and have a deeper understandin at this one because what others said it is hard to align in ASP.Net so I added a tag HTML in your code.

Here it is

[Align controls properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800303/align-controls-properly)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width on your control using the Width property (e.g. Width="150" for a 150-pixel-wide control), which in turn will create the corresponding inline CSS. This is the quick fix version.

If you want a more long-term approach, consider learning HTML5 and CSS. Here's a site that will give you the basics.

http://howtocodeinhtml.com/